# How can iterate on Access tables usine one tAccessInput component?

Tags: loops, talend

I have an MS Access database with many tables having all names in this format : products_stock_on_01/31/2020

fields are :

product_code
product_name
product_category
stock_quantity

Each month-end a new table is generated on this database.

With a simple Talend Job, an tAccessInput component and obviously a tMap.. i want to load all tables to one SQL Server table created in the same format with an additional field "Stock_date"

How can i do please ? I don't know how to make a loop on each table with her name in parameter for the tAccessInput compoent.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to create an iteration on the date, and adapt the query on your tAccessInput component to make it work on the current iteration table.

You could have a worflow as the following :

```
tFileInputDelimited --> tFlowToIterate-->tAccessInput-->tMap-->tDBOutput
```

- In tFileInputDelimited, you can put a csv file with only one column (lets say EndOfMonth), each line being a date (01/31/2020, 02/29/2020, etc). (You could also build a list of each end-of-month day from a Start date to an End Date, instead of having it in a file).
- tFlowToIterate will create a global Variable called EndOfMonth , and gives you an iteration link.
- in your tAccessInput component, modify the query like `"select * from products_stock_on_"+((String)globalMap.get("row1.EndOfMonth"))`   (this comes from tFlowToIterate, check the auto-completion.) It will create a query with the global variable, to query within each iteration a different table.
- in tMap, just add your new field
- Output is the insert in your DB.